# Upload Avatar To Server Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have looked into the best way to do this and keep getting conflicting information and advice on the various demonstrations.

My code is as follows...

html

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=265&d=identicon&r=PG" style="border: thin solid #999999;"/>
        <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#avatar-uploader').trigger('click'); return false;">Change</a><span class="pull-right">Powered by Gravatar</span></p>
        <input type="file" name="avatar-uploader" id="avatar-uploader" style="display: none;" />
```

javascript

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/upload-new-avatar.ajax.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
        alert("Success");
        }
        });
});
```

PHP: /ajax/upload-new-avatar.ajax.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
$sourcePath = $_FILES['avatar-uploader']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "".$_FILES['avatar-uploader']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
```

I'm sure there is something simple that I am missing here and i'm going to feel pretty stupid afterwards but could someone explain to me why the image isn't being uploaded to the server and saved in the AJAX directory for further processing.

What I need it to do is when the user clicks on the "change" hyperlink below the image it opens a file upload dialog (working), once an image has been selected it automatically uploads to the server over an AJAX connection (possibly working, logging shows the PHP file is being triggered), and then the image file needs to be saved in the AJAX directory to be further processed later in the code for it to be uploaded to the avatar service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i use [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) for uploading files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have managed to get it working...

Here is my amended code...

Javascript

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(event){
    files = event.target.files;
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening
    $("#avatar-status").text("Loading new avatar...");
    $("#avatar").css("opacity", "0.4");
    $("#avatar").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40);");
    //Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
        data.append(key, value);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/upload-new-avatar.ajax.php?files',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
                //Success so call function to process the form
                //submitForm(event, data);
                $("#avatar-status").text("Powered by Gravatar");
                $("#avatar").css("opacity", "");
                $("#avatar").css("filter", "");
            } else {
                //Handle errors here
                alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Handle errors here
            alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);

        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
session_start();
require_once("../libraries/logging.lib.php");
new LogEntry("AJAX Upload Started - UploadNewAvatar", Log::DEBUG, "AvatarUpload");
sleep(3);
$data = array();
if(isset($_GET['files'])) {  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();
    $uploaddir = '../tmp/';
    foreach($_FILES as $file) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name']))) {
            $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
            new LogEntry("UploadNewAvatar - Upload Successful", Log::DEBUG, "AvatarUpload");
        } else {
            $error = true;
            new LogEntry("UploadNewAvatar - Errors Occured", Log::ERROR, "AvatarUpload");
        }
    }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
} else {
    $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
    new LogEntry("UploadNewAvatar - Form was submitted successfully", Log::DEBUG, "AvatarUpload");
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

HTML

```
<img id="avatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?s=265&d=identicon&r=PG" style="border: thin solid #999999;"/>
        <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#upfile').trigger('click'); return false;">Change</a><span id="avatar-status" class="pull-right">Powered by Gravatar</span></p>
        <input type="file" name="upfile" id="upfile" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: I can't mark my question as answered by my own answer for 72 hours according to when I click the tick, apparently it is meant to give others an opportunity to post their own answers in case their answers are better.

Comment: works well for me, but changed `$_GET["files"]` by `$_FILES`.